# can't draw my rectangle where I want on the screen

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, 2d-games

I need to draw case/ spare which are Rectangle.

but the problem is that `glTranslated()`doesn't work. When I call it my rectangle isn't draw anymore.

my rectangle: `glRectf(-0.032f, 0.032f, 0.032f, -0.032f);`

(I don't understand values but working)

full code:

```
{
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  glLoadIdentity();

  glColor3ub(254,128,1);

  //glTranslated(50, 20, 0); when I remove the comment, my rectangle doesn't appear.                                                                                                                                             
  glRectf(-0.032f, 0.032f, 0.032f, -0.032f);

  glFlush();
  SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();
}
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem (including any necessary inputs, but preferably not needing any), then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

glRectf(x1,y1,x2,y2) means draw a rectangle from point (-0.032,0.032) to the diagonally opposite corner at (0.032,-0.032).

glTranslated(50,20,0) is applying a vector to move it. Those are pretty big numbers since you are saying you can see the rectangle (square) of size 0.064 wide. It may be drawing out of your viewport so you can't see it.
Try some small numbers and also glTranslated requires doubles (so I would cast them too).

Read more here...
http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/opengl_first_opengl_program.html